# How do I create a function that will create a global (and assign it a value) with a name that contains the name of the argument given to it?

Tags: python, global

I'm using Python and am trying to create a function that will look at the name of the object that is given as an argument and (among other things) create some globals that contain this name,
for example:

```
object1=someclass(args,kwds) #the object is an instance of a class that is given a certain name (e.g.object1)
def somefunc(some_argument):
   global tau_some_argument
   global ron_some_argument    #e.t.c. for other variables (I also would like to assign some variables etc)
   tau_some_argument=some_value1
   ron_some_argument=some_value2
   print ron_some_argument
   print tau_some_argument
```

now what I want to happen if I call this function is as follows:
when I call

```
 somefunc(object1)
```

I would like it to create some globals named tau_object1, ron_object1 and assign them values (the print statements are irrelevant), similarly if i called

```
somefunc(object2)
```

where object2 is another instance of a class I would like it to create globals: tau_object2, ron_object2, at the moment the function simply creates globals named tau_some_argument (as is obvious from the code).

Now I read somewhere that the names of python objects are immutable, unless they are a class or function so I don't know how to do this, from reading I get the feeling that I may need to use meta-classes but this feels like it's an overly complicated way of doing something that should be relatively easy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is *such* a bad idea...

Comment: if object1 is global, then you can use globals dictionary to find the key whose value is equal to some_argument. This gives you the name 'object1' or 'object2' or whatever.

Comment: But like Ignacio said, its a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a terrible idea...

```
def func(prefix):
    g = globals()
    g[prefix + '_tomato'] = 123
    g[prefix + '_broccoli'] = 456
```

Whatever you are doing, it can probably be done with dictionaries, arrays, and other objects in a way that isn't fragile like the above method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about python but can't you just declare a global array and simply create the object indexed by the name of the object as a string?

```
tau_some_argument['object1'] = some_value1
ron_some_argument['object1'] = some_value2
```

Comment: Maybe better indexed by the object itself?